# Deserialize XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize xml document into C# class. here is the document.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Exclusionpolicys>
  <Exclusionpolicy>
    <ValuationRoutes>
      <ValuationRoute>value1</ValuationRoute>
      <ValuationRoute>Value2</ValuationRoute>
    </ValuationRoutes>
    <ExcludeHives>
      <ExcludeHive name="samplename1"/>
      <ExcludeHive name="samplename2"/>
      <ExcludeHive name="samplename3"/>
      <ExcludeHive name="samplename4"/>
    </ExcludeHives>
  </Exclusionpolicy>
  <Exclusionpolicy>
    <ValuationRoutes>
      <ValuationRoute>Value3</ValuationRoute>
    </ValuationRoutes>
    <ExcludeHives>
      <ExcludeHive name="samplename5"/>
    </ExcludeHives>
  </Exclusionpolicy>
</Exclusionpolicys>
```

Here is the class I have created.

```
 [XmlRootAttribute("Exclusionpolicys")]
    public class ExclusionPolicys
    {
        [XmlElement("ExcludeHive ")]
        public ExcludedPolicyHives[] ExcludedHives { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ValuationRoute")]
        public ExcludedPolicyValuationRoute[] ValuationRoutes { get; set; }
    }


    public class ExcludedPolicyHives : IExcludedHives
    {
        public List<string> Hives { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExcludedPolicyValuationRoute
    {
        public List<string> ValuationRoutes { get; set; }
    }
```

When I Deserialize it...it doesn't throw any error but give me an object of ExclusionPolicys with null value for both properties.

Can anyone help with to identify what's wrong with my class definition.

I want to Deserialize it into keyValue pair list/array or similar to that.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for your help. Working copy is here...

```
[XmlRoot("Exclusionpolicys")]
    public class ExclusionPolicys
    {
        [XmlElement("Exclusionpolicy")]
        public List<Exclusionpolicy> Exclusionpolicy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Exclusionpolicy
    {

        [XmlElement("ValuationRoutes")]
        public List<ExcludedPolicyValuationRoutes> ValuationRoutes { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ExcludeHives")]
        public List<ExcludedHiveses> ExcludedHives { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("ExcludeHives")]
    public class ExcludedHiveses 
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ExcludeHive")]
        public List<string> Hives { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExcludedPolicyValuationRoutes 
    {
        [XmlElement("ValuationRoute")]
        public List<string> ValuationRoute { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class library to the below code since the XML Deserialixed must be consistent with the XML, ie: the Class Library must directly reflect the XML code-wise.

```
    [XmlRoot("Exclusionpolicys")]
    public class ExclusionPolicys
    {
        [XmlElement("Exclusionpolicy")]
        public List<Exclusionpolicy> Exclusionpolicy;
    }

    public class Exclusionpolicy
    {

        [XmlElement("ValuationRoutes")]
        public List<ExcludedPolicyValuationRoutes> ValuationRoutes { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ExcludeHives")]
        public List<ExcludedPolicyHives> ExcludedHives { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExcludedPolicyHives
    {
        [XmlElement("ExcludeHive")]
        public List<ExcludedPolicyHive> ExcludedPolicyHive;
    }

    public class ExcludedPolicyValuationRoutes
    {
        [XmlElement("ValuationRoute")]
        public List<ValuationRoute> ValuationRoute { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExcludedPolicyHives
    {
        public string Hives { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExcludedPolicyValuationRoute
    {
        public string ValuationRoutes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have changed and why you have changed it?

Comment: @Default- What you see here in the question, the second part that indicates the working code, was my original reply to him, which was, supposedly, 80% correct.

Comment: When I originally saw the question, it only had the first part. I supplied the second part.

Comment: @Default- The Changes are I made later on were the bottom 4 classes

Comment: I understand that you added code, but could you explain *why*? Why should extra code be added? What was missing in the original code which made it not work? An answer with just code is good enough, but an answer with code and an explanation is great

Answer (score 0):

There is a converting tool built in Visual Studio 2012 - I don't know how it looks with other VS.

1. Create any new project with .Net Framework >=4.5.
2. Copy your XML into clipboard.
3. Choose Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as classes.

Now you have classes generated, you don't have to create it manually.